# How do I get my PDF email attachment to attach correctly as a PDF?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, email-attachments

Below I've added a screenshot of the attachment as it appears in the email.

It opens fine in any PDF reader.

How do I get it to present as an actual PDF? I feel as though I've missed something small...

Here's my code:

```
public ActionResult SendInvoice(SendInvoiceViewModel model)
{
    var Invoice = db.Invoices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Invoice.Document);

    Attachment Data = new Attachment(ms, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
    ContentDisposition Disposition = Data.ContentDisposition;
    Disposition.CreationDate = Invoice.Date;
    Disposition.ModificationDate = Invoice.Date;
    Disposition.ReadDate = Invoice.Date;

    SendInvoiceMail(model.EmailAddress, Invoice.Number, model.EmailMessage, Data);
}

private void SendInvoiceMail(string emailAddress, string invoiceNumber, string message, Attachment attachment)
{
    using (MailMessage Message = new MailMessage())
    {
        Message.From = new MailAddress("accounts@###########");
        Message.Subject = String.Format("Your store invoice {0}", invoiceNumber);
        Message.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress));
        Message.Body = message;
        Message.Attachments.Add(attachment);

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.############", 587);
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("info@##########", "##########");
        smtp.Send(Message);
    };
}
```

So what did I miss?

[image: Email Addtachment]

Comment: I'm probably not seeing right, but where do you set your filename ?

Comment: I don't... Not sure where to do that but per answer by Ollie Jones below, I'm willing to bet I do that on the correct overload of `Attachment()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using the 3-parameter version of the [`Attachment()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ds708xx(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor. The second parameter lets you give a file name. That file name should end in `.pdf`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
public ActionResult SendInvoice(SendInvoiceViewModel model)
{
    var Invoice = db.Invoices.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Invoice.Document);

    //Construct a file name for the attachment
    var filename = string.Format("{0}.pdf", Invoice.Number);

    Attachment Data = new Attachment(ms, filename, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
    ContentDisposition Disposition = Data.ContentDisposition;
    Disposition.CreationDate = Invoice.Date;
    Disposition.ModificationDate = Invoice.Date;
    Disposition.ReadDate = Invoice.Date;

    SendInvoiceMail(model.EmailAddress, Invoice.Number, model.EmailMessage, Data);
}
```

Where you include the file name for the attachment.